# Finding Words In List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make something that finds where a word is in a list and then tells you where it is here is what i have so far:

```
whenAppears = 0
when = []
i = 0
phrase = str(input("What sentence? "))
phrase = phrase.lower()
phrase = phrase.split()
print(phrase)
wordel = str(input("What single word would you like to find? "))
wordel = wordel.lower()
if wordel in phrase:
    print ("That word is in the phrase, there are",phrase.count(wordel),wordel+"('s)""in the sentence")
for word in phrase:
    whenAppears += 1
    if wordel == phrase[i]:
        when.append(whenAppears)
print ("The word",wordel,"is in the slot",when)
```

no matter what i put in it says the word is in slot 1 and any other slots, i cant think of any ways to pic this, please help :D

Comment: Take a look at the [`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) method for a more efficient way to find the position of an item in a list of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `whenAppears += 1` after the `if` block. Change `wordel == phrase[i]` to `wordel == word`. Delete the line `i = 0`.

Corrected code:

```
whenAppears = 0
when = []
phrase = str(input("What sentence? "))
phrase = phrase.lower()
phrase = phrase.split()
print(phrase)
wordel = str(input("What single word would you like to find? "))
wordel = wordel.lower()
if wordel in phrase:
    print ("That word is in the phrase, there are",phrase.count(wordel),wordel+"('s)""in the sentence")
for word in phrase:
    if wordel == word:
        when.append(whenAppears)
    whenAppears += 1
print ("The word",wordel,"is in the slot",when)
```

You could make your code nicer with comprehensions and `enumerate`, but these are the errors you definitely have to fix.

Comment: Thank You SO Much :DDDDDD!!

Answer (score 0):

You use the loop in an incorrect way.
You must compare `wordel` with `word`, because any time you loop over `phrase`, the value is stored in `word`.

```
for word in phrase:
    whenAppears += 1
    if wordel == word:
        when.append(whenAppears)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your code more efficiently with `list.index`:

```
phrase = str(input("What sentence? ")).lower().split()
print(phrase)
wordel = str(input("What single word would you like to find? ")).lower()
if wordel in phrase:
    print ("That word is in the phrase, there are",phrase.count(wordel), wordel+"('s)""in the sentence")
    print ("The word",wordel,"is in the slot", phrase.index(wordel))
```